# Matlab angle2dcm different definition

Tags: matlab, rotation, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

I am using MATLAB function angle2dcm which gives me different results from what I expected. By digging into the code (angle2dcm.m) I found the definition of forming the rotation matrix is different from the standard one.

For example, rotation Rx*Ry*Rz (i.e. 'xyz' order) is defined as:

```
%     [          cy*cz, sz*cx+sy*sx*cz, sz*sx-sy*cx*cz]
%     [         -cy*sz, cz*cx-sy*sx*sz, cz*sx+sy*cx*sz]
%     [             sy,         -cy*sx,          cy*cx]
```

while normally it should be (please refer to the link):
http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/

Is it different definition of direction cosine matrix and rotation matrix?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with notation conventions, since the two cases (MATLAB versus the link you posted) refer to opposite orders of rotation. If you want to use the MATLAB function and continue to use the convention from the link you posted, as a possible workaround you can call the function with 'zyx' and invert the signs of all the angles, i.e.

```
 dcm = angle2dcm( -r1, -r2, -r3,'xyz');       *EDITED*
```

which uses the following rotation matrix (see matlab documentation)

```
         [          cy*cz, sz*cx+sy*sx*cz, sz*sx-sy*cx*cz]
         [         -cy*sz, cz*cx-sy*sx*sz, cz*sx+sy*cx*sz]
         [             sy,         -cy*sx,          cy*cx]
```

If this is confusing you could even wrap everything in a helper function that does the sign and order inversion for you, something like

```
 function dcm = angle2dcm_mines( r1, r2, r3);
 dcm = angle2dcm( -r1, -r2, -r3,'xyz');
```

There are other ways to work around this but that should work.

Comment: a quick comment: the default order for Matlab angle2dcm function is 'zyx'. To inverse the order, 'xyz' can be used.

Comment: @linzhang.robot thanks for your comment, I made an edit. Hope it's ok now.

Comment: Hello @TryHard, can you help me to solve this problem with dcm please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049658/from-direction-cosine-matrix-to-cardan-angles-two-different-matlab-codes-diff?noredirect=1#comment6288044_3049658

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling with this for a while now and, thanks to posts like this, have (just about) managed to get my head around it. here is my twopence worth which i hope helps and gives something back.

it's a pain because there are 24 sets of options for application of euler angles (general term but there are various variants inc. tait-bryant, pitch-yaw-roll etc.) depending upon the order in which the rotations are applied, whether or not the last rotation is about the same axis as the first and whether or not they are intrinsic (i.e. the frame rotates and subsequent rotations are applied about the new frame) or extrinsic (all rotations are applied about the original, fixed/world frame). there are some more common sets such as (extrinsic) XYZ and ZXZ.

it is important to note that the rotation (aka direction cosine) matrix for XYZ is equivalent to (intrinsic) zyx and this is a common rule (i.e. switch the first and last rotations). in terms of the rotation matrix this is manifested by taking its transpose and switching the sign of the sin functions. MATLAB uses the intrinsic rotation approach. note that, in terms of the individual rotations, they are applied by pre-multiplication with the first rotation being the furthest to the right.